# how to get rid of NOUN tag for unknown words in Spacy POS tag?

Tags: python, spacy

I am doing POS tag for some texts. I use spacy to get POS tags. Why I am getting NOUN tags for unknown words? for instance, If I pass sbxdata, I am getting noun tag for that. I hope there is no meaningful word as sbxdata. What I want is, I shouldn't get any tags for unknown words or I want to get only POS tags for common English words. Any libraries/any approaches available for this?

For instance, I am having the below sentence.

**value large column sbxdata actual maximum ptsavatar**

for this, I am getting the below POS tags.

[image]

How to get rid of the Noun tag for sbxdata and ptsavatar. Similarly, I need to get rid of any random tags for unknown words. Also, I suspect, by default it is giving as NOUN. Any help would be really appreciated.

This is my code.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])
doc = nlp(" ".join("value large column sbxdata actual maximum ptsavatar"))
print('NLP doc :::', doc)
for token in doc:                    
  print('token :::',token,' --> token.pos_ :::',token.pos_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I did not find a clear notice about this in the [spacy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#pos-tagging)
but as it seems, your guess about the default assignment of NOUN is correct.

There were some suggestions to use spacy's vectors to determine if a word is a true English word. This did not work for me, however.

What about using a plain old spell checker? At least the 2 obvious cases in your example can be filtered out with [pyspellchecker](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/).

```py
import spacy
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner'])

spell = SpellChecker()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doc = nlp("He who values value large column sbxdata actual maximum ptsavatar")

    known = set(spell.known([token.text.lower() for token in doc]))

    for token in doc:
        if token.text.lower() in known:
            pos = token.pos_
        else:
            pos = ""

        print(f'{pos:5s} {token}')
```

gives me

```
PRON  He
PRON  who
VERB  values
VERB  value
ADJ   large
NOUN  column
      sbxdata
ADJ   actual
ADJ   maximum
      ptsavatar
```

Answer (score 0):

A POS tagger tries to find a tag for each token (or word) which fits the word best. If you use unknown words like sbxdata in a sentence, it's more likely you use it as a noun. Think of it syntatically rather than semantically. Here is an example: "I want to get rid of sbxdata." Although in this sentence sbxdata has no known meaning, it IS used as a noun in the sentence actually. So it's not that random in fact.

Also keep in mind since a POS tagger MUST find a tag for any given word, it is normal if the tagger has a hard time finding the right tag, it just returns a default tag like noun.

Comment: Can you provide a link `NOUN` is a default?

Comment: I'm not sure if spacy uses noun as default but i think it woud be a good idea, since noun is the most likely tag in most corporas. Check https://www.nltk.org/book/ch05.html (section 4.1 the default tagger) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify some misconceptions.

SpaCy *doesn't have* a concept of a default `TAG`, except for being an Out-of-Vocabulary may produce a bias in model predictions. What spaCy does for `TAG` assignment is using:

> Convolutional layers with residual connections, layer normalization and maxout non-linearity are used, giving much better efficiency than the standard BiLSTM solution.

to predict *multilabel* class probabilities:

> This convolutional layer is shared between the tagger, parser and NER, and will also be shared by the future neural lemmatizer. Because the parser shares these layers with the tagger, the parser does not require tag features. I got this trick from David Weiss’s “Stack Combination” paper4.
>
> To boost the representation, the tagger actually predicts a “super tag” with POS, morphology and dependency label5. The tagger predicts these supertags by adding a softmax layer onto the convolutional layer – so, we’re teaching the convolutional layer to give us a representation that’s one affine transform from this informative lexical information. This is obviously good for the parser (which backprops to the convolutions, too). The parser model makes a state vector by concatenating the vector representations for its context tokens. [source](https://spacy.io/models)

You can find the source code for prediction [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/pipes.pyx#L409)

The magic of choosing certain TAG out of multilabel probabilities happens [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/pipeline/pipes.pyx#L421):

```
doc_guesses = doc_scores.argmax(axis=1)
```

This is a simple `argmax` out of an array of predictions. In general in Machine Learning there will be no "default" value, unless one has a very strong reason to do so.

Back to the OP:

> How to get rid of the Noun tag for sbxdata and ptsavatar.

The TAG's assigned are reasonable choices of the model based on the vectors, including OOV vector all zeros, and info about surrounding tokens (see the links above). If you do not like them for some reason, I can think of 2 scenarios:

1. either you drop/substitute what you don't like with a dummy token <UNK_TAG> eg, or
2. retrain your model from scratch by assigning the words that look strange <UNK_TAG> in raw text input

Note, in both cases you'll need to define what is acceptable and what is not